# Html/Css center a div in a div vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

Hello all here's my question:

I have an html/css website and I have several parent and child div's. I need to make a script (Jquery?) that finds the parent and the child div height's and add the css necessary to center the child in the parent...

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>
.....
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>
....
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>

<SCRIPT>
???
</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks all...

Comment: Ciao Filippo! Can you please post any jQuery you tried so far? so not only we can show you how to do it, but also understand what you know already and hopefully - guide you with more info. Additionally it would be really helpful to know if your children will always have a fixed height (or it might vary from element to element)

Comment: consider just adding another class to the divs that is for the parent and for the child, then use the vertical align css attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var childHeight  = $('.child').css('margin-top', function() {
    var childHeight = $(this).height();
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    return ((parentHeight - childHeight) / 2);
  });
});
```

Basically, after the document has been loaded,
 you retrieve heights of all DOM elements with class *child* and relative fathers,
you need this to calculate the **margin-top** value of the child obj.

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ujobaw/8/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.parent').each(function(){

  var $pa = $(this);
  var $ch = $pa.find('.child');
  var paH = $pa.innerHeight();
  var chH = $ch.innerHeight();

  $ch.css({marginTop: (paH-chH)/2});

});
```

If you'll have images inside your `.child` I suggest you to assing to that images a `height=""` property, or to put the JS inside a function and recall it on `$(window).load(function(){ /*here*/ });`

Comment: Very clean solution! Kudos! But we should use scripts only if the issue cannot be solved using straight-forward CSS.

Comment: @RomiHalasz I agreee with you, that's why I started my answer with: *with jQuery:* :)

Comment: I agree too, but I don't know a flexible way to do that only with css

Comment: I like your solution, you can change '.child' with '>.child' if you have a nested structure.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I thought I would just improve the readability. Other than that, no other changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood u i think u can do it with this bit of css:

```
.parent {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden; /* This actually makes height auto */
  padding: 10px 0; /* exmaple of 10px up and down that will actully center it with some space IF space is needed*/
}
```

Comment: he want JavaSript, not CSS.

Comment: Cause sometime, he need javascript to work with other thing else. so you should propose javascript/jquery with css is the best.

Answer (score 0):

No need of using jQuery here, you can use `overflow:auto` combination with `margin` as shown in the below link.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/axikuz/1/edit)**

```
.parent{overflow:auto;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;margin-bottom:10px;}
.child{width:50px;height:50px;background-color:blue;margin:25px;}
```

You can also replace pixels with percentages here.

This can also be done using `float` or `display` properties instead of `overflow:auto`.

Comment: I don't know the width and height as they should change in a responsive way

Comment: This css solution works in all divs with differents content heights? If your contents are written by server side code you can't know the child height before..

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to set the `display` property of the parent div to `table-cell`. Here is the code:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; height:200px; border:1px solid red; vertical-align:middle; align: center;">
    <div style="height:100px; border:1px solid blue;">The content</div>
</div>
```

And this is what it looks like:

http://screencast.com/t/6kB9ec1uV

You don't need a script, unless you want to do something else besides centering the child div. Have a great day !